# IF statement with nested vlookup in google sheets

Tags: function, google-sheets, nested

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LVLS69csWIrL3w3eRxQj2XpLwLS4VGaLGn48a4X8KqE/edit#gid=0

Trying to pull over roles, the vlookup below works on its own and pulls over roles, but if it pulls over nothing and the cell is blank I'd like it to say "No Primary" in the cell instead of leaving it blank. The IF statement below(which was found from scouring the SO site) is giving a Formula parse error and Circular dependency detected. I'm sure it's something tiny I am overlooking. Any help would be appreciate. Thanks!

=vlookup(C3, 'Team Chart'!$D:$K, 8,0)
=IF(ISBLANK(D3),"No Primary")

=IF(NOT(ISBLANK(D3)),vlookup(C3,'Team Chart'!$D:$K,8,FALSE),"No Primary")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that the cell you're using is D3. if it is, than you can't ask "ISBLANK(D3)" and put the result in cell D3.

What you probably what to do is use IFERROR for this task, sinse VLOOKUP returns N/A error for values not found in the lookup array:

`=IFERROR(vlookup(C3,'Team Chart'!$D:$K,8,FALSE),"No Primary")`

Comment: IFERROR wont work as it is not pulling an error it is just pulling blank if the person has no primary assigned to them. So instead of blank I want it to say no primary. Based off what you are saying though, it seems like what I need can't be done since I am using D3 to pull the information into. C3 is the agents name and D3 is where the vlookup is placing the role.

Answer (score 0):

Did a bit more research and digging as well as some trial and error. Found that a combination of If/IFERROR and VLOOKUP worked like a charm. Thank you for a point in the right direction @mrras

=IF(ISBLANK(D3),"NO Primary",IFERROR(VLOOKUP(C3,sheet2!A:B,2,FALSE), ))